# Gradle run test classes in parallel with methods of same class running in same thread

Tags: java, gradle, junit, springrunner

I'm having a few Junit test classes. I want to run them in 2 threads, so included `maxParallelForks = 2` . I want to make sure that tests of same class run in same thread sequentially. How to achieve this? (I use SpringRunner.)

Answer (score 1):

I was using `@RunWith(Suite.class)` to run multiple test classes. So I created a new Runner class and this solved my problem.

```
public class ParallelExecutor extends Suite {

    public ParallelExecutor(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError, IOException, InterruptedException {
        super(klass, builder);

        setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {

            private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                service.submit(childStatement);
            }

            public void finished() {
                try {
                    service.shutdown();
                    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from a quick look at the Gradle sources, this should exactly be the option you want. `maxParallelForks` make test **classes** be executed in parallel, not single test methods.